# Pandas write back to dataframe after filter and calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `data` which contains items and price. For each item iteration, I want to calculate normalized price and write it back to the column `"Price_Norm"`. The problem is that only the last iteration has the result and previous iterations are empty.

Below are the codes, use 2 items with 2 price each for simplicity:

```py
d = {
    'itemName': ['Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog'],
    'Price': [1, 2, 3, 4],
    'Price_Norm':[0,0,0,0],
}

data = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
items = ['Cat', 'Dog']

data_c = data.copy()
for this_item in items:
    this_item_data = data_c[data_c['itemName']==this_item]
    normalized_price = this_item_data['Price'] - this_item_data['Price'].max()
    data['Price_Norm'] = normalized_price #<--- FIXME
```

Each item calculation is fine, the dataframes of `normalized_price` has correct indices and values. However, after the loop only the last item `dog` gets the mormalized price, all the previous ones are empty, even default value 0 are now empty.
I think the last line `Price_Norm` assigment needs to be fixed, it needs to write to matching indices ONLY and not override other rows to empty. What is the correct way doing so?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
data['Price'] = data.groupby('itemName')['Price'].apply(lamda x : x - max(x))
```

Comment: Thanks that works well and much better using group by. Just to learn, If I want to correct my last line what would would be the solution?

Comment: The problem I see in your code is that `normalized_price` and `data` do not have the same shape, your last line could be `data[data['itemName']==this_item] = normalized_price`. Which may not work - I don't have local environment to test it - and is not the best practice (less readable).